# How to type a generic payload of {key, value} to a specific property of an Interface?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

In react I have an interface for my global state as follows:

```
export interface GlobalState {
  colorPicked: string | null
  anotherValue: number | null
}
```

And also I have an Action that defines what the payload should look like (it should be part of the GlobalState defined above)

```
type OfType<T> = {
  key: keyof T
  value: T[keyof T]
}

export interface SetState {
  type: 'SET_STATE'
  payload: OfType<GlobalState>
}
```

The problem arises when I use my dispatch function, it can correctly infer the `type` but for the `value` it gives me all the possible types of `GlobalState` (string, number, null).

[image]

Is there a way to specifically match the `key` to a property of `GlobalState` but also to match the value of that key only?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use generics all the way up:

```
type OfType<T, K extends keyof T> = {
  key: K
  value: T[K]
}

interface SetState<K extends keyof GlobalState> {
  type: 'SET_STATE'
  payload: OfType<GlobalState, K>
}
```

I'm not too familiar with how (what I assume to be Redux's) `dispatch` works with TypeScript, but you may have to make that function generic too.

Answer (score 1):

Your current `OfType` does not have any relationship between the `key` and `value` properties.

You can define a better `OfType` using mapped types to create a union of all possible pairings.

```
type OfType<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: {
    key: K;
    value: T[K];
  }
}[keyof T]
```

This type makes it so that `{ key: 'colorPicked', value: 5 }` is not a valid payload, but `{ key: 'colorPicked', value: '#FFFFFF' }` is valid.

[TypeScript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w8J90m)

Your setup does seem excessively complicated and can probably be simplified quite a lot by using [Redux Toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAction).